# how can i get different result each elements in react?

Tags: reactjs

I'd like to know how to get different results from each items with using select options.
my code is like this:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Home = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState();

  const clickCheck = e => {
    setState(e.currentTarget.value);
  };
  const members = ["Jake", "John", "Steve"];
  return (
    <div>
      {members.map(member => (
        <>
          <h1>{member}'s choice</h1>
          <select onChange={clickCheck}>
            <option value="a">a</option>
            <option value="b">b</option>
            <option value="c">c</option>
            <option value="d">d</option>
          </select>
        </>
      ))}

      <div>
        kim's choice: <p>{state}</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        park's choice: <p>{state}</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        lee's choice: <p>{state}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

I'm trying to get specific results from the option and i want to use only one useState and one function . but I have no idea what i should do with it .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a dictionary to store choice of members

```
  const [choices, setChoices] = useState({});

  const clickCheck = (member) => (e) => {
    setChoices({
      ...choices,
      [member]: [e.currentTarget.value]
    });
  };
```

#### Live example

[image: Edit tender-water-2u3fg]

Answer (score 2):

Use object to store the state of each member instead of a single state.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Home = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({});

  const onOptionSelected = (e, member) => {
    // If the member name has spaces and uppercase letters, remove spaces or convert to lowercase before setting the member name as a key on the object for easy accessing. Its recommended to store the data in object using some unique ID for each user instead of name as a key. 
    setState({...state, [member]: e.currentTarget.value});
  };

  const members = ["Jake", "John", "Steve"];
  return (
    <div>
      {members.map(member => (
        <>
          <h1>{member}'s choice</h1>
          <select onChange={(event) => onOptionSelected(event, member)}>
            <option value="a">a</option>
            <option value="b">b</option>
            <option value="c">c</option>
            <option value="d">d</option>
          </select>
        </>
      ))}

      <div>
        Jake's choice: <p>{state.Jake}</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        John's choice: <p>{state.John}</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        Steeve's choice: <p>{state.Steve}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Comment: Thanks Sir ! i got an syntax error from  `setState({...state, state[member]: e.currentTarget.value});` this part

Comment: change it to, setState({...state, [member]: e.currentTarget.value});